# On-premises Gateway installation problem Windows Server 2016 - NET Framework required

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, .net-framework-version, windows-server-2016

I`m working with the client Windows Server 2016 and I need to connect Azure Logic App infrastructure to the folder in that wirtual machine.

When I tried to install the Gateway [it complained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5akr5.png) that NET Framework is not installed or requires higher version. However in the [Server Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mZH5.png) I see that there is a NET Frame of 4.6 version installed, and I`m not sure if there is an option to update that.

I tried to install web NET Framework 4.8 and it was successful, asked for reboot. I reboted the server and looks like it change nothing. NET Frame did not appeared in programs list and the Gateway still complains and refuses to work. I tried to install NET Frame 4.8 again using diferent installer.

I also tried NET Frame 4.8.1 and it did not install because my device did not meet requirenments.

Comment: The oldest supported version of .NET Framework is 4.6.2. if the gateway requires 4.8, that's what you have to install though. `it did not install because my device did not meet requirenments.` what was the actual error? .NET Framework 4.8 [*does* support Windows Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-server-operating-systems)

Comment: 4.8 installed with no error. 4.8.1 made an error saying that the device is not good enough

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your .NET Framework 4.8 failed to install. That is the version that is listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install as the prerequisite.

There are various ways to install it, try and use the offline installer (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows-9d23f658-3b97-68ab-d013-aa3c3e7495e0) and make sure you have admin priviles (run as admin).

Comment: I tried an offline installer and also tried as an admin. It was a successful installation and it asked me to reboot my device. I tried to install it many times, maybe there is something else that I`m missing